# How to updates the information stored in the TIB

Tags: windows, assembly, stack, mingw, thread-local-storage

I want to move the stack of my threads, I saw this sentence in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block

> A process should be free to move the stack of its threads as long as it updates the information stored in the TIB accordingly. A few fields are key to this matter: stack base, stack limit, deallocation stack, and guaranteed stack bytes, respectively stored at offsets 0x8, 0x10, 0x1478 and 0x1748 in 64 bits. Different Windows kernel functions read and write these values, specially to distinguish stack overflows from other read/write page faults (a read or write to a page guarded among the stack limits in guaranteed stack bytes will generate a stack-overflow exception instead of an access violation). The deallocation stack is important because Windows API allows to change the amount of guarded pages: the function SetThreadStackGuarantee allows both read the current space and to grow it. In order to read it, it reads the GuaranteedStackBytes field, and to grow it, it uses has to uncommit stack pages. Setting stack limits without setting DeallocationStack will probably cause odd behavior in SetThreadStackGuarantee. For example, it will overwrite the stack limits to wrong values. Different libraries call SetThreadStackGuarantee, for example the .NET CLR uses it for setting up the stack of their threads.

I tried the **SetThreadStackGuarantee** function only to modify the **GS:[0x1748]** field, is there any other api under windows that can modify **GS:[0x08**], **GS:[0x10]** and **GS:[0x1478]**?

Comment: Have you tried [_writegsbase_u64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/x64-amd64-intrinsics-list?view=msvc-170)?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I don't think that intrinsic is helpful for OPs purpose; it's for changing the TIB base, not for writing to addresses in the TIB.

Comment: @fuz Oops, my bad.  The one you want is a couple down from there: `__writegsqword`: *Write memory to a location specified by an offset relative to the beginning of the GS segment.*

Comment: The supported way of doing stack switching is SwitchToFiber.